# How to split query builder in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have three variables and I only want to add certain where clause if those variables are not null or blank.

```
$brand = $request->brand == 0 ? "" : $request->brand ;
$category = $request->category == 0 ? "" : $request->category ;
$subcategory = $request->subcategory == 0 ? "" : $request->subcategory;

$items = Item::select('items.*','brands.brand_name','category.category_name','subcategory.subcategory_name')
            ->leftJoin('brands','items.brand_id','=','brands.id')
            ->leftJoin('category','items.category_id','=','category.id')
            ->leftJoin('subcategory','items.subcategory_id','=','subcategory.id');

if($brand != ""){
    $items->where('items.brand_id',$brand);
}
if($category != ""){
    $items->where('items.category_id',$category);
}
if($subcategory != ""){
    $items->where('items.subcategory_id',$subcategory);
}
$items->get();
```

Now I am getting below error

> 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to
>   string'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$items` is an Eloquent Builder instance so take output in other variable:

```
$items = Item::select('items.*','brands.brand_name','category.category_name','subcategory.subcategory_name')
                    ->leftJoin('brands','items.brand_id','=','brands.id')
                    ->leftJoin('category','items.category_id','=','category.id')
                    ->leftJoin('subcategory','items.subcategory_id','=','subcategory.id');

if($brand != ""){
    $items->where('items.brand_id',$brand);
}
if($category != ""){
    $items->where('items.category_id',$category);
}
if($subcategory != ""){
    $items->where('items.subcategory_id',$subcategory);
}

$data = $items->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this part as like this. assign your `$items` variable every condition.

```
$items = Item::select('items.*','brands.brand_name','category.category_name','subcategory.subcategory_name')
            ->leftJoin('brands','items.brand_id','=','brands.id')
            ->leftJoin('category','items.category_id','=','category.id')
            ->leftJoin('subcategory','items.subcategory_id','=','subcategory.id');

if($brand != ""){
    $items = $items->where('items.brand_id',$brand);
}
if($category != ""){
    $items = $items->where('items.category_id',$category);
}
if($subcategory != ""){
    $items = $items->where('items.subcategory_id',$subcategory);
}
$items = $items->get();
```

Comment: check this part brother. you didn't assign variable 
`$items = $items->where('items.brand_id',$brand);`

Comment: @YasinPatel He is restoring $items everytime he adds a where condition, you are not..this is the right way

Comment: And we gave the answer at same time as well it's different from you.

Comment: $items = $items->get(); this is ok , no  need  to assign every time like this : $items = $items->where()

Answer (score 0):

```
$Items = DB::table('Item')
            ->join('brands','items.brand_id','=','brands.id')
            ->Join('category','items.category_id','=','category.id')
            ->Join('subcategory','items.subcategory_id','=','subcategory.id');
             ->select('items.*','brands.brand_name','category.category_name',
               'subcategory.subcategory_name')
            ->get();

      dd($Items);
```